# Angular: Let the user create objects with a form

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm pretty new to Angular and I've run into the problem that I want the user to be able to fill out a form with String-Data which should then create an object to be displayed in a list. I'm not sure how to do that, all of the Tutorials and examples for displaying lists I've found use MockData for example purposes, so I don't know how to connect the user input to the list-display.

Here's the code (.ts) of the individual elements of the list:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from '../project';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-project',
 templateUrl: './project.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./project.component.css']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {
 openform = false;

 newProjectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: '',
  pjNummer: '',
})

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

onSubmit() {
 this.openform = false;
 this.newProjectForm.reset();
 return this.openform;
}

onClickOpenForm() {
 this.openform=true;
 return this.openform;
}
}
```

And .html:

```
<div>
 <button (click)="onClickOpenForm()" 
 value="Register">Neues Projekt eintragen</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="openform">
    <form [formGroup]="newProjectForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div>
            <label for="name">
            Projektname:
            </label>
            <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="pjNummer">
            PJ-Nummer:
            </label>
            <input id="pjNummer" type="text" formControlName="pjNummer">
        </div>
  
        <button (click)="onSubmit()"
        class="button" type="submit">Erstellen</button>
        
    </form>
</div>
```

And the code for the list itself (.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-list',
  templateUrl: './project-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-list.component.css']
})
export class ProjectListComponent{

  projects: any[];
  
  constructor() {}
}
```

And .html:

```
<h2> Erstellte Projekte </h2>
<ul class="projects">
    <li *ngFor="let project of projects">
        <h3>{{project.name}}</h3>
        <div><span>Name: </span>{{project.name}}</div>
        <div><span>Pj-Nummer: </span>{{project.pjNummer}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So basically, what I'm looking for is a way to add a project with the data the user put into the form into the 'projects: any[]' list whenever the form is submitted, but I'm not sure how to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value method for the form group
this.newProjectForm.value();
Before this.newProjectForm.reset();
It will return all the data user entered